# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell with delete capabilities

Tags: objective-c

I created a custom cell and upon click, it should display a popup.
However, when this is works successfully, it seems to create an issue where I am not able to click the delete button.[image]

It seems that my `UITapRecognizer` supercedes my method to delete.(Means the popup is displayed instead when I click the delete button )

Any idea how to solve this?

Below is my code to handle tap in the cell (`OfficeCell.m`)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openOfficePopover)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    self.textLabel.textColor = mRgb(0x3a, 0x6c, 0x99); 

     }
    return self;
}
```

Below is my code to handle the delete in the `ViewController` :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

       NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
       if (section ==1 )
       {
          return YES;
       }
       return NO;
  }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

        if(section == 1)
        {
            [_sectionOffice removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        [self.formView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realize that the fix should be really simple :

changing 2 lines of code solve the issue :

From :

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

To :

```
[self.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```